# Embedded videos inside UIWebView dont fit the bounds of full screen, only on iOS10

Tags: ios, uiwebview, fullscreen, ios10

I load a UIWebView with an html script that contains embeeded video (almost all from youtube). Reproducing videos was working ok. But since this was tested on iOS 10 the full screen takes all the screen but the video itself dont increase nothing, just only center and dont change size. But if i try with iOS 9 or 8 the full screen resize the video to fit all the screen [image: Full screen video][image]
I think iOS has implemented new rules about the default video player on webview, or something is missing on the html script. I was trying to add tags like  on the script and css rules, but nothing yet. Thanks.

Comment: Apple States in their API reference: "In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView."

Comment: Yes, it's working now the full screen, nice dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if on iOS 10，use wkwebview，otherwise uiwebview，if else solve it

Comment: tell me whether is ok please

Comment: if really help，accept and vote，I will edit my answer more easy help other